# How to implement OnClick item using firebase search query result item

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a firebase search query and it works perfectly.But now I can't seem to figure out how to do the onlick and get item position. Below is my firebase search activity:

```
mUserDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("UserProfile";
        mSearchField = findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
        mResultList = findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();
                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
            }
        });
    }
    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Searching......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("profession").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
                Users.class,
                R.layout.search_list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getUsername(), model.getSummary(), model.getImageurl());
            }
        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        private TextView user_name;
        private TextView user_summary;
        private ImageView user_image;
        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName,String userSummary,String userImage){
            user_name = mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
             user_summary = mView.findViewById(R.id.summary_text);
            user_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            user_name.setText(userName);
            user_summary.setText(userSummary);
            Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Hello,How may i help you", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

How do i go about displaying the content in a details activity when a single item from the search result is clicked.

Based on **Parag Pawar's** suggestion, I tried the following, but it's not working>

```
       @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getUsername(), model.getSummary(), model.getImageurl());
            final String each_key = getRef(position).getKey();


        }

    };
```

Then in my UserViewHolder i initialized the onclick:

```
  mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent pDetail = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ProfileDetail.class);
                Users each_key = each_key.get(getAdapterPosition());
                pDetail.putExtra(ProfileDetail.EXTRA_POSITION, each_key.getUserId());
                startActivity(pDetail);


            }
        });
```

But I am getting the error ***variable each_key might not have been initialized***

Fixed my mistake according top advice from **Parag Pawar** and implemented he onclick inside populateView`holder as follows:

```
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*Here use intent.putExtra() to send each_key on other activity and fetch data there*/
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "u clicked......" +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent each_key = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ProfileDetail.class);
                    Users user = mResultList.get(position);
                    each_key.putExtra(ProfileDetail.EXTRA_POSITION, user.getUserId());
                    startActivity(each_key);



                } });
```

but I am getting the error here:

```
 Users user = mResultList.get(position);
```

**Cannot resolve method 'get(int)'**

mReultList is the name of my Recyclerview and I initialized it as follows:

```
private RecyclerView mResultList;
```

but I don't know if I'm doing this correctly. I know I am supposed to attach the results to an adapter, but I don't know how to do that. So I tried:

```
  listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UsersList>(listItems,this);
```

But this doesn't seem to work either

**Updated Code**

I created an array:

```
 private List<UsersList> listItems;//UsersList is my modal class
```

Then added it to my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then Implemented putExtra as follows using this array as follows:

```
Intent each_key = new Intent(TestSearch.this, ProfileDetail.class);
                    UsersList user = listItems.get(position);
                  //Here use intent.putExtra() to send each_key on other activity and fetch data there
                    Toast.makeText(TestSearch.this, "u clicked......" +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    each_key.putExtra(ProfileDetail.EXTRA_POSITION, user.getUserId());
                    startActivity(each_key);
```

But getting this error when i click an item:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                  at com.ecard.ecard.search.TestSearch$2$1.onClick(TestSearch.java:94)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the activity that contains your current
items that you want to click on:
Create a String to reference from in your populateVieHolder:

```
 final String single_view = getRef(position).getKey();
```

Then attach an onclick to your ViewHolder:

```
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
```

And in your **OnClick** place your *intents* and **putExtras**:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
//give your intent a name to reference from("moreDetail" in this case)
Intent moreDetail = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,MoreDetail.class);
//attach the intent reference to access each item and key 
moreDetail.putExtra(MoreDetail.EXTRA_POSITION,single_view);                       
startActivity(moreDetail);//Start the new activity
```

Then in your more details activity:
Add the ExtraPosition String

```
 String single_view = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MoreDetail.EXTRA_POSITION);//get extra position reference previous view
```

From here on,you need to display your data from firebase

**For accessing Single Values from Firebase**

```
    firebaseRef.child(single_view).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //For single items
// for example:String user_name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
```

**Or**

**For accessing Values attached to your adapter using a Listview**

```
 firebaseRef.child(single_view).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
ListItem data = dataSnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);
                listItems.add(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //if you are accessing your data from a ListView
```

There are so many ways to do this.Another way to accomplish this is to create an interface.declare an onclick listener and contex in your recycler adapter:

```
 OnItemClickListener callback;
private Context mContext;
```

Then implement an Onclick listener to your view holder

```
public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnItemClickListener  {
```

add an onclick to access a position,to your View Holder using callback:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        callback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

Then create an interface:

```
 public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int pos);
    }
```

Based on your context:
In your more main activity:

```
   @Override
public void onItemClick(int pos) {

    Intent pDetail = new Intent(this.getContext(), ProfileDetail.class);//get the context
    ListItem listItem = listItems.get(pos);//get the position
    //Then your puEtxra here followed by start activity
    startActivity(pDetail);
}
```

And finally call EXTRA_POSITION in your detail view followed by your datasnapshots.
You can find more details from the firebase documentation and firebase quick start samples on github:
[GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)
[FirebaseDocs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: This is perfect.Thank you.It helped me solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

To get key from each item, in populateViewholder do
Example :-

```
final String each_key = getRef(position).getKey();
```

To set Click Listeners on each item, in populateViewholder do

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
            /*Here use intent.putExtra() to send each_key on other activity and fetch data there*/

   } }); }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.Its not working.Please see edited question where i implemented your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I said both the things go in populateViewHolder() 
You are getting not initialized error because you're using each_key in the Viewholder class.

> Copy this

```
    final String each_key = getRef(position).getKey();
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
/*Here use intent.putExtra() to send each_key on other activity and fetch data there*/ 
} }); }
```

and paste it in the populateViewHolder method

Comment: With your code,Even withought an intent,merely by pressing the search button,the app is crashing: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]

Comment: Never mind,i fixed the null pointer exception.Now trying to do the onlick.I placed a toast on the onclick and its getting displaying the correct position.Now i cant figure out how to use the intent.putExtra

Comment: Please assist me bro..i cant seem to get around using putExtra when there is nothing to attach to the adapter.I know how to do this with custom Adapter and recycler adapter the old fashioned way.but i dont know how to do this with firebaserecycler @parag pawar

Comment: What is your question about ? How to use putExtra or attach adapter to recyclerview...also show the logs what error is actually

Comment: How to use putExtra to display more details to the next activity on each item

Comment: Bro,ive added the log error and the code i used to get this error

Comment: nothing seems wrong..but still try giving context in onClick as 
 `v.getContext() ` instead of  `SearchActvity.this`

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after adding v.getContext(),:::: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0:::

Comment: The traditional method of recycler adapters requires ::::: @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
To be added to the adapter.Theres a possibility that this is why i am getting this error.But i dont know how to implement Index and Size using firebaserecycler

Comment: Then after populateViewHolder method try overriding `getItemCount()` it is available in `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: The error is gone,but now the search is not producing any results any more,when i remove the : @Override 
public int getItemCount() { return listItems.size();} the search function produces results,but with it there are no results when i search

Comment: This issue happened with me but i was dong something else..
Don&#39;t declare `String searchText` inside onClick . Don&#39;t know how this make sense but this solved my issue once. Declare it just before OnCreate method

Comment: Are you refering to declaring search text as a variable?Then just using mSearchField.getText().toString();
                firebaseUserSearch(searchText); in the mSearchBtn onclick?Because if thats the case,im still not getting results when i press the search button